# Should I use form to submit JSON data to REST api

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms, reactjs

Is it approved to use a html form to build interface to collect user data, convert it to domain model in front end and POST it to server using JSON?

I like to think the user input part as a logical form, event though the server expects JSON. For user it is all the same, so why not just to use a form to collect the data and implement a custom onSubmit method? Another option would be use detached input fields and buttons.

Is this considered a good practice to use forms for JSON POST and what are the good and bad consequences of this practice?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my thought on this:

**Pros:**

1. Potentially you can re-use web services to perform form validation as well as acting as a standalone service. Make sure you really have this need before implementing this non-standard method.

**Cons:**

1. You are moving away from standard form/post models which is a basic feature of HTML for several years.
2. Your users will be forced to use JavaScript - not such a big deal in 2016 but you are losing accessibility for... what gain?
3. You will have to manage this requirement for multiple browsers (adds potential complexity).
4. Possibly the page load rank will be slower depending on your implementation. This might impact SEO and user experience.

I see a lot more cons thant pros, but maybe your situation truly justify this?

Answer (score 1):

Grouping inputs and submit buttons within a `<form>` is semantic and good practice, it simply requires calling `preventDefault` on the event passed to your `onSubmit` handler to prevent the hard form submit. Your API should speak JSON, and it's trivial to save your form values into state values into state onBlur/onChange, and use jQuery or some other lib to create a JSON post.  While its not completely necessary, I cannot think of drawbacks.  Fallbacks for the "no javascript" scenario aren't realistic now for most use cases.

Answer (score 1):

i think its a bad approach.

in client side, do client logic, ui logic, etc...
in server side do your processing.

also in many API you will need credentials/token...you sure you wanna share those on cliend scripts (: ??